# C++ simulate left mouse click on minimized program

Tags: c++, winapi, simulation

I have been searching for a bit about this particular problem I am having, I want to be able to simulate a left mouse click on a program that I am currently attached to.

Right now, I create a thread that checks a database for certain values, and when those values come back (the ones I am looking for), I want to be able to then send a left mouse click in any x,y coord of the program (while minimized).

How can this be done for Windows 7?  Thanks!

EDIT: Here is how I am calling the thread ...

```
HWND child = GetActiveWindow();
if ( child == NULL )
MessageBox(0,"Couldn't get the child hwnd!","",0);

DWORD ID;
HANDLE thread_check_game = CreateThread ( NULL , 0 , (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) game_check_thread , (LPVOID)child, 0 , &ID ); CloseHandle ( game_check_thread );
```

and then ...

```
DWORD WINAPI game_check_thread(LPVOID lpParam) {

HWND    Window;
Window = (HWND)lpParam;
// ... some other code ...
// ...
WORD mouseX = 398;
WORD mouseY = 398;


SendMessage(Window,WM_LBUTTONDOWN,MK_LBUTTON,MAKELPARAM(mouseX,mouseY));
SendMessage(Window, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(mouseX, mouseY));
Write("Sent Left Click\n");

ExitThread(0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is are variants of this same question asked almost weekly? Do people not search anymore?

Comment: [Same question in .Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029453/simulate-mouse-click-on-a-minimized-window?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to fire a mouse event in your application, use the `SendMessage` function, and your message will appear in the window with handle `hWnd`'s message pump.

```
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(mousePosX, mousePosY));
```

You may need to notify for `WM_LBUTTONUP`, depending on the way you application handles it's mouse events.

Comment: That is not working, as a note, it is not my application, as I am injecting a dll into the program.

Comment: Try with PostMessage rather than SendMessage (real mouse messages are posted, and the target app may be looking for them in its message loop rather than in the window procedure). Also the target app may be specifically ignoring input when it is minimized.